# What does "still on my watch" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, translation

I translate the dialogue from the game, I want to get its interpretation:

> I still on my watch even after hundred years.

I don't understand sense of the phrase "still on my watch". What means it in this sentence?

Comment: Hi Dillian - this isn't a site that offers free translation. If you [edit] to add some detail we might be able to reopen your question though. What is making it hard for you to understand the sentence? There's some advice in the [Details please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/) discussion for what sorts of detail to add. You may want to also check what is on-topic here in the [help] : https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: **ColleenV** I edited my question.

Comment: The sentence you have quoted is not grammatical. It lacks a verb.  Have you looked up the meaning of the noun, **watch**?

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence has no verb. It should be like the following

> I am still on my watch.

**To be on the watch** is an idiom meaning "to be on the alert" for some danger or something of the kind.

Answer (score 0):

> on my watch

is a phrase to signify the duration of time when someone is responsible, their *watch*.

> Not on my watch.

is used to say not to do something when you are responsible.

I think your sentence might be

> I *am* still on my watch even after *a* hundred years.

which means they are still responsible for things even after such a long time.